# How to read file and send to other URL

Tags: node.js, filestream

How to read file from file system and send that to another URL ? Its similar to CURL request which we use in other languages.

I have tried following, but that is not working.

```
fs.createReadStream(files.upload.path).pipe(request.post('http://localhost/test.php', function (err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log(body);
                    res.end();
                }
            }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your arguments. You want the callback to be sent to `request.post`, not `pipe`:

```
fs.createReadStream(files.upload.path).pipe(request.post('http://localhost/test.php', function (err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log(body);
                    res.end();
                }
            }));
```

Also, it's generally a bad idea to `throw` errors in asynchronous code.